# Add indentation to lineage in GSP page

Tags: css, grails, gsp

I am trying to list a descendancy starting from root and printing its children's children. The domain looks something like

```
class Node {   

    String nodeId
    String label

    Node parent    
}
```

Note I dont have a reference to child instead i have a reference to its parent.

In the GSP page I want to list the entire lineage but I am not able to get proper indentation where each node will have an indent for its child. Basically need some kind of checking condition that if the previous node is the parent of the next node give it an indent otherwise find the parent of next node and put it there accordingly.

```
<concepts>      
        <g:each in="${nodes}" var="node">               
                <concept  id="${node.id}" description ="${node.label}">
                </concept>                  
        </g:each>    
</concepts>
```

Something like (ignore the text. i need a structure like [this](http://www.infragistics.com/community/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.38.92.01/Tree_2D00_Table_2D00_Description.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to: [Recursion in GSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129073/recursion-in-gsp-page)

Update the _node.gsp template:

```
<g:if test="${nodes}">
<ul>
  <g:each in="${nodes}" var="node">
    <li>
      ${node}
      <g:render template="node" model="[nodes:Node.findAllByParent(node)]" />
    </li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
</g:if>
```

And style accordingly.